# how can I get specific guild id from ready event?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

so what I am trying to do is to get this bot works on multiple servers so I want to get a specific guild id same like using `message.guild.id` but since there is no message defined or declared how can I get it, any ideas?

Thank you

code here:

```
const db = require(`quick.db`)
let cid;
const { prefix } = config

client.on('ready', async () => {


  console.log(`${client.user.tag} is online`);
  console.log(`${client.guilds.cache.size} Servers`);
  console.log(`Server Names:\n[ ${client.guilds.cache.map(g => g.name).join(", \n ")} ]`);


  loadCommands(client)
  cid = db.get(`${message.guild.id}_channel_`) // this line - 14 


 
  cron.schedule('*/10 * * * * *', () => {
    const zkrRandom = zkrList[Math.floor(Math.random() * zkrList.length)]
    const zkrEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()


      .setDescription(zkrRandom)
      .setAuthor('xx', logo)
      .setColor('#447a88')




    client.channels.cache.get(cid).send(zkrEmbed);
  })

  client.on("message", async message => {




    if (message.author.bot) {
      return
    }
    try {if (!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR') && message.content.startsWith('!s')) return message.reply('you do not have the required permission') } catch (err) {console.log(err)}
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;


    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g)
    const cmd = args[0]
    if (cmd === "s") {
      let c_id = args[1]
      if (!c_id) return message.reply("you need to mention the text channel")
      c_id = c_id.replace(/[<#>]/g, '')
      const channelObject = message.guild.channels.cache.get(c_id);

      


      if (client.channels.cache.get(c_id) === client.channels.cache.get(cid)) return message.reply(`we already sending to the mentioned text channel`);
      if (client.channels.cache.get(c_id)) {


       
        await db.set(`${message.guild.id}_channel_`, c_id); //Set in the database
        console.log(db.set(`${message.guild.id}_channel_`))

        message.reply(`sending to ${message.guild.channels.cache.get(c_id)}`);
        cid = db.get(`${message.guild.id}_channel_`)



        const zkrRandom = zkrList[Math.floor(Math.random() * zkrList.length)]
        const zkrEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()


          .setDescription(zkrRandom)
          .setAuthor('xx', logo)
          .setColor('#447a88')




        client.channels.cache.get(cid).send(zkrEmbed);



      } else {
        return message.reply("Error")
      }


    }
  })
})




client.login(config.token)
```

---

the error I got

```
cid = db.get(`${message.guild.id}_channel_`)
                  ^

ReferenceError: message is not defined
```

Comment: `client.guilds.cache.get('GUILD ID')` or `client.guilds.fetch('GUILD ID')` and resolve the promise

Comment: what I mean is not to initialize a specific guild id, I want to fetch the guild id like when you did something like this `message.guild.id` or it is not possible in my case?? I hope you get my point, sorry for any confusion

Comment: If you have a guild name you can use `client.guilds.cache.find(g => g.name == '...');`

Answer (score 0):

Guild name and id these such data storage under `guilds.cache`. Therefore, with the same way for you to get all guild name that your bot has joined. You can simply change `name` into `id` to get all guild id of the guilds that the bot has joined. This will return in array form.

```js
console.log(client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.id)) // ['1234567890', '0987654321']
```